# Cannot import a project into workspace (no message error)

Tags: android, import

I have an old Android project sitting in another laptop. I try not to change its contents for when I have to look at its codes. But when I tried to look at it, I cannot seem to import it on my workspace. I do not have any existing project in my workspace. I have also tried deleting my "workspace" folder so I could start anew, but it still won't work. There are no error messages, it just won't import.

Comment: What are you trying, and what IDE are you using?

Comment: And what are you trying...

Comment: I'm simply trying to import a project to my workspace. But it won't import, there are no error messages, it won't build (the one at the right bottom)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same has happened to me.

The solution was to create a new project, add the classes from the old project and all necessary libs.

Have you experience yourself this solution? I know it is not the most correct, but if consigas not otherwise experience. Can you then know which classes have errors.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a bit lost, how can I add the classes from the old project if I can't open it?

Comment: You create a new project, and copy/paste de java files from old project folder to the new one. Click on project with rigth click and select refresh (f5). The java files will be apear.

Comment: You mean the "classes" folder under bin? Just that? Thank you so much!

Comment: No, bin folder is not important! Copy only the files inside your src folder. And all resources (of course). Mark this answer as "correct answer" if your problem is solved ;)

Comment: After doing this, I saw the classes in my project explorer but they only show random characters, not actual codes.

Comment: You are copy .class files or .java classes? You have to copy only java files! For example, you not need to copy bin folder! Be more expecific, to i try help you;)